# Size of Iterable<Type>

Tags: java, generics, iterable

Suppose a method returns `Iterable<Type>`. Is there a more elegant and efficient way to check whether what is returned is empty (or of some given size) than what I'm doing now?

```
int i = 0;
for (Type dummy : method)
  i++;

if (i == 0)
...
```

Comment: you are doing nothing

Comment: Check if not empty: `Iterator#hasNext()`. For a given size, there is no other solution (AFAIK).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the an `Iterable` is empty using `iterator().hasNext()`.

```
    Iterable<Type> i = /* assigned somehow */;
    i.iterator().hasNext();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Guava's [Iterables.isEmpty](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.Iterable%29):

```
boolean empty = Iterables.isEmpty(method);
```

To find a size of an Iterable there is also [Iterables.size](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#size%28java.lang.Iterable%29):

```
int size = Iterables.size(method);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Iterable` it provide `iterator()`. Check `hasNext()`.

And se the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator<String> itr = collectionObject.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
//process here with next method on itr object
}
if (element.equals("")) {
System.out.println("Empty...");
}
```